# Codeigniter mysql_connect for Quercus resin

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, quercus

I use Tomcat and Quercus.

Quercus want mysql_connect, How add mysql_connect argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_connect()` has been deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0` as per the below document
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Make sure why you need `mysql_connect` to do it. The betterway to connect MySQL it is by using `mysqli_connect`.

**Codeigniter** provides the facility for mysqli by default. You just need to create a `model` as specified [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)